# Is there a word for sad & angry?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am trying to find a word or phrase that would express being sad and angry.   Any suggestions?

Comment: "Sad and angry". 'Sad' is a passive idea and 'angry' is active. If you want both words together you'll have to give up on one of those.

Answer (score 8):

It's unusual to see someone display anger and sadness at the same time. Without further context, I can suggest **"sullen"**, which implies a silent and gloomy irritation.

- a sullen look, attitude, manner
- a sullen countenance
- sullen students protests

> **"sullen"** -  gloomily or resentfully silent or repressed. (implies a silent ill humor and a refusal to be sociable) [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sullen)

Comment: Processing grief by directing anger at your surroundings doesn't seem unusual to me—it's one of the most common ways of reacting.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet   Yes, Janus, that's common.   People react in different ways, and concealled grief can be expressed through anger, aggressiveness, hostility, belligerancy, etc.

Comment: I don't think it's so unusual to be sad and angry at the same time, so I disagree! But thank you for the word. Except that, your answer is perfect (would need to be edited in the "unusual" part though.

Comment: @Quidam    "**display** anger and sadness",  not "feel" or "be"

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [***resentful***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resentful) captures the feeling.

> Feeling or expressing bitterness or indignation at having been treated unfairly.
>   *‘he was angry and resentful of their intrusion’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resentful

Answer (score 1):

It's more angry than sad, but **bitter** could work.

> [bitter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bitter) (adj.) - expressive of severe pain, grief, or regret

Since a phrase is acceptable, you can simply use **reluctance** for the "not wanting something to happen" part.

> [reluctance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reluctance) (n.) - the state of being reluctant
>   [reluctant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reluctant) (adj.) - feeling or showing aversion, hesitation, or unwillingness