# What is a word describing 'angry and sad at the same time'?

Tags: single-word-requests

**What is a word that describes being angry and sad simultaneously?**

I am writing a story in which there is a part where I'm frustrated/angry but also sad at the same time. I want a word to describe this.

Comment: Maybe https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sullen

Comment: This question was asked previously, but no satisfying answers emerged: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/354710/206976

Answer (score 4):

**Disgruntled**

> unhappy, annoyed, and disappointed about something

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/disgruntled)

Comment: *Unhappy* does not equal *sad*, so this doesn't really work for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Tetchy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tetchy)  (Cambridge Dictionary) easily made angry, unhappy, or upset

[Soured](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soured)   (Merriam Webster)  :

> bad, wrong a project gone sour
>
> hostile, disenchanted
>
> ```
> "went sour on Marxism"
> ```
>
> Unpleasant, distasteful, cross, sullen